# 'DISPLAY' ERROR while trying to run a Python script that imports PyAutoGui on GoogleColab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pyautogui

I have a Python script that I am trying to execute on `GoogleColab` for its GPU resources. The script uses `PyAutoGui` and works perfectly on my local system but it crashes during import on `GoogleColab`.

Why is this happening??

When I try to run the script on `Colab`, this is the error that I am getting:

```
2024-01-26 22:31:32.030010: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-01-26 22:31:32.030065: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-01-26 22:31:32.031387: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-01-26 22:31:33.164963: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/webcam.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 680, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

What is this DISPLAY error? How to fix this help please!!

Comment: It looks to me like there's an environment variable `DISPLAY` that's set on your local machine but not on colab, i.e. see the line containing `Display(os.environ['DISPLAY']`. You'll need to figure out what it's value is locally and then set it on colab (probably using `os.environ`)

Comment: i.e. on you local machine add some debug code `print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])` if you don't know what it contains.